# Compiling parts of AOSP outside the source tree

Tags: android, makefile, android-source, rom

I'd like to compile small, standalone parts of the AOSP outside the source tree. Normal way to compile screenshot (`android/framework/base/cmds/screenshot`) utility would be to execute `make screenshot` in the tree roor (`android/`). How can I compile modified version of screenshot if it's placed outside the tree?

Answer (score 3):

So I am working with 4.4.2 and I'm not sure what version you are using, but generally Android has used an odd build system as far back as I can remember. Without getting into the details, to build components of AOSP you typically build them within the source tree after sourcing envsetup.sh which includes a variety of tools and functions that the Android.mk files use and understand (along with some of the other .mk files in the tree).

A lot of these components in AOSP have dependencies on other components in the source tree. If the component you are trying to make does not, then it shouldn't be too hard to construct a standard make file for it. Otherwise if it has dependencies, life will get complicated (it's probably already complicated if you are trying to separate components of AOSP).

You would have to build the components and make a new make file that includes those components manually. You could build those components through the AOSP tree, or you could keep following the chain up until your dependencies don't have dependencies and separate those. Then build those, make make files for the other components that require them, build those, etc. etc.

So that's how you would do it as far as I am aware. I really don't recommend it.